# There are two carousel slides running in same line this app but I want only one. please tell me what is Problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

There is no error in this code
but nothing is understood as to what is causing the two slider.
See in this android emulator working two carousel.
please tell me what is a problem in this code.
Do not understand what to write now, how long has this stockoverflow been told, add some more details,
minds spoiled, so I am writing this, Sorry, do not pay attention to this, pay attention to question.

[image]

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Carousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselState createState() => _CarouselState();
}
class _CarouselState extends State<Carousel> {

  var api = Uri.parse('http://192.168.43.162/flutter/bannerApi.php');
  var response;
  var bannerApi;
  @override

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
// for loading
    fetchData();


  }
  fetchData() async {
    response = await http.get(api);
    print(response.body);
    bannerApi = jsonDecode(response.body);

    setState(() {});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
           body: Center(
          child: response != null
              ? Stack(

                  children: List.generate(
                  bannerApi.length,
                  (index) => CarouselSlider(
                    items: [

                      //1st Image of Slider
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(

                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(bannerApi[index]['img']),
                            // image: AssetImage(assignmets[index]['img']),

                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                    //Slider Container properties
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 180.0,

                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      autoPlay: true,
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,

                      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                      viewportFraction: 0.8,
                    ),

                  ),
                ))
              : CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,

                )),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a api data.

```
[{"img":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1517245386807-bb43f82c33c4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"},{"img":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1517245386807-bb43f82c33c4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"},{"img":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1517245386807-bb43f82c33c4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"},{"img":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1517245386807-bb43f82c33c4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"},{"img":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1517245386807-bb43f82c33c4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"},{"img":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1517245386807-bb43f82c33c4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"}]
```

Comment: you are creating a Carousel for each item of bannerApi.

Comment: So what should I do with the API to bring the image into the carousel slider

Comment: you can have a single carousel inside stack and for stack items you can use list.generate

Comment: I do not understand what to do in the code, can you modify the code and give it? If you don't mind then.

Comment: @HabibMhamadi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537861/error-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value , please check this one i don't understand anything what is problem in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your stack I am using a container.

```
Container(
 child: CarouselSlider(
   items: List.generate(
    bannerApi.length,
    (index) => Container(
       margin: edgeInsects.all(6.0)
       ...
```

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515391/error-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value-or-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtyp